# Changing a layer's label font size using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, labeling

I'd like to increase the font size of my layer "Grid". The field is "MAPSHEET" on Grid's attribute table. I've tried all sorts of ways to write it out in code to no avail. I'm teaching myself how to code and it's quite the slog; just sick of repeating functions in GIS. Any ideas?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
for m in aprx.listMaps("Map"):
    for lyr in m.listLayers("Grids"):
        lblClass = lyr.listLabelClasses()[0]
        print(lblClass.name)
        lblClass.expression = "$feature.MAPSHEET"
        lyr.showLabels = True
```

Comment: You can also use percentages rather than hard-coding the font size, which is better if you change the base font size.

Answer (score 5):

Change

`lblClass = "$feature.MAPSHEET"`

to

`lblClass = "\"<FNT size = '30'>\" + $feature.MAPSHEET + \"</FNT>\""`

Comment: lblClass.expression = "\"<FNT size = '30'>\" + $feature.MAPSHEET + \"</FNT>\""

Comment: Thanks Kadir! I had tired a few expressions and so totally failed it wasn't even worth mentioning. 

Once I added "expression" to "lblClass" it worked perfectly!

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment: I was trying to edit it, I hadn't realized you'd responded. Anyhow, yes, your initial suggestion didn't work, but lead me down the right path.

Comment: Could you please add your solution as an answer using "Answer Your Question" button below.

Answer (score 1):

To highlight Kadir's (and mine, but let's be honest it's Kadir's) answer:

```
lblClass.expression = "\"<FNT size = '48'>\" + $feature.MAPSHEETNA + \"</FNT>\
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's what works in context:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
for m in aprx.listMaps("Map"):
    for lyr in m.listLayers("Grids"):
        lblClass = lyr.listLabelClasses()[0]
        print(lblClass.name)
        lblClass.expression = "\"<FNT size = '48'>\" + $feature.MAPSHEET + \"</FNT>\""
        lyr.showLabels = True
```